# Python: Join lists of lists by the first element

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to combine a list of lists/tuples by the first element in the list - something like this:

Input:

```
[(1, [32, 432, 54]), (1, [43, 54, 65]), (2, [2, 43, 54]), (2, [1, 5, 6])]
```

Output:

```
[(1, [32, 432, 54], [43, 54, 65]), (2, [2, 43, 54], [1, 5, 6])]
```

The lists are actually ordered by the first element like in my example input, and it doesn't matter if at the end the tuples are lists.

Is there an efficient/pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Probably, yes. Did you try anything to solve this problem? Do you have any code you can share with us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = [(1, [32, 432, 54]), (1, [43, 54, 65]), (2, [2, 43, 54]), (2, [1, 5, 6])]
>>> import itertools
>>> [(key,) + tuple(v for k, v in grp)
...     for key, grp in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])]
[(1, [32, 432, 54], [43, 54, 65]), (2, [2, 43, 54], [1, 5, 6])]
```